# Extracting data from corrupted string

Tags: r

Hi I have a dataframe with a column in which the variable is email. Unfortunately, something went wrong and several of the email id have number prefix seperated by underscore. These are the two patterns I have noticed.

Is there a way to extract the data after the underscore, if we processing from the left. Can some logic be built so that the script is smart enough to check if there is one underscore or two. I can do this in excel using `find()` and `right()` functions but was wondering how to accomplish this in R.

For example:

```
product$email

83837_83838_abcd@gmail.com
83837_abcd@gmail.com

output
abcd@gmail.com
abcd@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub`

```
sub('.*_', '', str1)
#[1] "abcd@gmail.com" "abcd@gmail.com"
```

Or

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, '[^_]+$')
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c('83837_83838_abcd@gmail.com', '83837_abcd@gmail.com')
```